# How to write isset with exclamation mark

Tags: php

I just need clarification.

I have this code below:

```
if ((!$username) && (!$userid))
```

but I want to include an isset with this code. Is the correct way of typing this is below:

```
if ((!isset($username)) && (!isset($userid)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it to see if it does what you want?

Comment: The `!` operator has a higher precedence than `&&`, so you can use `(!isset($username) && !isset($userid))`, which is arguably easier to read.

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)).

Comment: Also, since you are new here, you should consider selecting an answer as the accepted one. You can do this by clicking the check mark underneath the number of votes an answer has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is fine and should work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be really fancy, isset() can take multiple parameters and returns true if all of them are set. So, you could do

```
if (!isset($username,$userid))
```

Edit: This isn't exactly what you asked for. The code in the if block will be executed when *either* $username or $userid is not set. In the original post you want the if to be executed when *both* $username and $userid is not set.

Comment: You are right @Jack. This does need to be the way Tim Cooper or Wayne Whitty has stated for complete semantic and functional equality.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you have the expression `!$x` and you wish to also add `!isset($x)`, it might be better to use `empty`:

```
if (empty($username) && empty($userid)) {
    // both $username and $userid are either non-existent or "empty"
    // "empty" is defined as: evaluates to false (see manual page)
}
```

It also simplifies the condition, no negations used :)

See also: [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: But empty and isset are different. An array can be empty and still be set. http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle but OP mentions he wants to have his first conditions and *add* `isset()`; `!(isset($x) && $x)` intuitively sounds like `empty()` to me.

Comment: I think that empty is still a good recommendation though, as many beginning developers tend to look at isset() as a definitive result on whether or not the variable has a value, not whether or not it is set.  In this case, the OP probably already has $username and $userid defined somewhere (pulling from $_POST or $_GET) and will likely always have isset returning true.

Answer (score 1):

Your second piece of code will work. But so will this:

```
if( !isset($username) && !isset($userid) )
```